# CVAT REST API - provide a list of users registered on the server without paginate

Tags: api, cvat

I found a API `api/v1/users` which can provide a paginated list of users registered on the server.
But, in fact, I want to get all registered users.
Is there any API I can use to get all registered users?
Or, with API `api/v1/users`, which parameter I can set for getting all registered users?
https://cvat.org/api/swagger/

Answer (score 0):

Use can use any of the below statements to achieve this...

```
http://<your_host_ip>:<django_active_port>/api/users
```

or

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://<your_host_ip>:<django_active_port>/api/users' \
  -H 'accept: application/vnd.cvat+json'
```

In order to get all the available APIs you must go to `<your_host_ip>:<django_active_port>/api/swagger` for more details. If you did not change the port, hopefully `<django_active_port>` should be `8080`. Now all you just have to put your `host ip` in the above queries. Hope this **[link](https://opencv.github.io/cvat/docs/administration/basics/rest_api_guide/)** helps.